# Find Max/Min Relative from Java Collection

Tags: java

I have a Java ArrayList which contains a set of numeric values.
There are several options to find the highest/lowest value from a Java Collection. On the other hand, I'm struggling to find the Relative Min/Max Relative of these values.
If we use a graph to draw the ArrayList values, here are the points I'm looking for:

[image]

So I'd need to find the id those elements from the ArrayList. I see the package Apache Math has several built-in functions to calculate derivatives but that doesn't seem so straightforward many years after one studied it at school. Any Java coder with Math skill that can give me a clue?

Comment: For each point in the list, check if it is greater than both of its neighbours (local maximum) or less than both of its neighbours (local minimum). That is, compare `list.get(a)` with `list.get(a-1)` and `list.get(a+1)`.

Comment: A derivative would assume you have a continuous function, not a set of discrete points. Perhaps a bar graph would be better visualization

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That helped me to simplify the problem. It's quite clear!